# IntelliJ not loading transitive dependency in maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've made a small library, lets call it `lib`. It dependends on another library, `sublib` which is available in Maven central:

`lib/pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>3rdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>sublib</artifactId>
        <version>x</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now I'm trying to use `lib` in my project `proj`. I've set it as a dependency:

`proj/pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mynamespace</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
        <version>y</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run `mvn exec:java -D exec.mainClass=mynamespace.proj.Main` the program runs fine.
However if I run it from IntelliJ, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 3rdparty/SomeSubLibClass
    at mynamespace.SomeLibClass.method(SomeLibClass.java:100)
```

This seems to indicate that IntelliJ does not load the transitive `sublib` dependency. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sometimes I have to right click on the `pom.xml` in the file tree, and select `maven > reimport`. (In case you didn't try this already)

Comment: @kuporific Thanks, that fixed it! I tried "synchronize" and similar options already but didn't find that yet... If you make it into an answer I'll accept it

Comment: In this context "synchronize" means "synchronize with the file system" which is non-intuitive if you have Maven on the brain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually right click on the `pom.xml` file in the file tree and select `maven > reimport`.

Sometimes you'll see a popup saying "Maven projects need to be imported"; you should select `Enable Auto-Import`.

[image: Maven auto import popup]

This option can be found in `Preferences > Maven > Importing > [x] Import Maven projects automatically` (and is unchecked by default):

[image]

Comment: The auto-import was on though, so that didn't fix the problem

Comment: I'd be curious if anyone has ideas for solving this when re-importing DOESN'T fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing from using maven (Intellij) version and using my latest version that was installed on my machine previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The below command resolved the problem. It downloaded all the dependency jars into my IDEA project.

```
mvn -U idea:idea
```